# React - writing form data to file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that has a form getting user input.. Instead of the regular submit button that sends the form data, I want to be able to write this data to a file so it can be used at a later time.

Can this be done using vanilla JS or is there a library that may be more helpful?

My handle submit method looks like this:

```
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      parameters: {
        startTime: this.state.date,
        selectors: this.state.selectors,
        offset: this.state.offset,
        "length.seconds": this.state.lengthSeconds,
        "runtime.seconds": !this.state.checked
          ? this.state.runtimeSeconds
          : undefined
      }
    });
    console.log(data);
  };
```

So normally this would send the data inside the form state to the URL I specify.

Let's say I want to take this data inside of the form state, instead of submitting, write it to a file.

```
  handleSave = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      parameters: {
        startTime: this.state.date,
        selectors: this.state.selectors,
        offset: this.state.offset,
        "length.seconds": this.state.lengthSeconds,
        "runtime.seconds": !this.state.checked
          ? this.state.runtimeSeconds
          : undefined
      }
    });
    // write data to csv file here.
  };
```

Is this possible to do? Is there a certain library that would be helpful here?

I have a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k3nj00vwn7) here with a larger demonstration of my component and form

Comment: You need to send to the server anyway, the browser can't write files, so you end up sending it anyway. What server technology do you use? That's where you would do it!

Comment: What do you mean I need to send it to the server anyway? If I just want to save it to disk why would there need to be server communication involved?

Comment: You might want to check out something like https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could use `localStorage.setItem('myData', data);`

Comment: @pigeontoe this would be more so for caching the data locally right?. My idea is to have the file be exported/imported in different places, be able to send the file to another user where they could import this data. So if I just needed this data to persist in the browser if the user navigated away, local storage would be super useful here.

Comment: I see. Yeah, localStorage will just keep it in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the following function in your `handleSave` function:

```js
function download(filename, text){
  var blob = new Blob([text], {type: "text/plain"});
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url;
  a.download = filename;
  a.click();
}

download("text.txt", "file contents here...");
```

List of MIME types here: https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list

Comment: I ended up using this solution, something similar you could do as well: `<a href={`data:text/xml;base64,${btoa(response.data)}`} download="foo.xml">click me</a>`

I'm getting the raw xml back so you `btoa` the response or a variable if you're setting it to state. But with the solution I mentioned you have to render a second button, and in my case the button needed to do two things asynchronously so your solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try similar to below:

```
   import React, { useState } from 'react'

   export default () => {
     const [formdata, setFormData] = useState({})
     const onChange = event => setFormData({ ...formdata, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
     const downloadableData = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(formdata, null, 2))
     return <React.Fragment>
       <form>
           <input type="text" name="name" onChange={onChange} value={formdata.name || ''} />
           <input type="text" name="address" onChange={onChange} value={formdata.address || ''} />
           <input type="text" name="emailId" onChange={onChange} value={formdata.emailId || ''} />
       </form>
       <a href={`data:applicatiom/json,${downloadableData}`} download="formdata.json">Download Form Data</a>
   </React.Fragment>
 }
```